# MySQL, how to get rows that have certain columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
|  ID1   |  ID2  |
------------------
|   1    |   1   |
|   2    |   1   |
|   3    |   1   |
|   4    |   1   |
|   5    |   1   |
|   6    |   1   |
|   7    |   1   |
|   8    |   1   |
|   9    |   1   |
|   10   |   1   |
|   11   |   1   |
|   12   |   1   |
|   13   |   1   |
|   1    |   2   |
|   2    |   2   |
|   5    |   2   |
|   1    |   4   |
|   9    |   4   |
```

Some of the ID1s have both the 1 and 4 values like this:

[image: Wanted values]

And I would like to return the ID1s like this:

```
|  ID1   |
----------
|   1    |
|   9    |
```

I have tried some basic queries but Im not even close.. I just cannot get this to work even remotely and I need some serious help with this one.

Comment: Is `ID1` supposed to have only one unique value?

Comment: In this instance, `WHERE id2 =4` would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id1
from yourtable
where id2 in (1,4)
group by id1
having count(distinct id2) = 2
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61143/1)

Comment: Distinct is (hopefully) redundant. If it's not, then the OP has bigger problems!

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If `ID1` is supposed to have only one unique value then the following query would work for you:

```
SELECT 
 ID1
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ID1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID2) > 1;
```

**EDIT:** May be you are looking for those entries having `ID2 as 1 and 4 both`.

```
SELECT 
 ID1
FROM your_table
WHERE ID2 IN (1,4)
GROUP BY ID1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ID2) = 2;
```

**Note:** It would have been better if you clarify what combination of `ID1 & ID2` is supported in your table.

Comment: At first glance I thought `ID1` is supposed to have only one unique value. The first answer is based on this assumption. It didn't match actually with the actual requirement. That might be the reason behind downvoting. @JPG

Comment: @1000111 Your edit seems to be correct but someone else beat you to it. I'll give you a "thumbs up" -credit for it as a thanks!